# Note 8: Whatsapp crashing after verification, while showing restoring backup

Tags: samsung, backup, whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I got a Note 8 yesterday, and have been moving my data from my older Note 4. Everything worked after a struggle, but I've been working on this for hours with no luck.

Basically, I verify, then Whatsapp shows "Looking for backups" then crashes.

What I tried:

1. Uninstalled and resinstalled Whatsapp
2. Clear data and cache
3. Delete all older whatsapp data directories in the SD Card and External SD Card (except for the media directory, but I renamed the whole Whatsapp directory).
4. All orders of above combinations

I'd like to point out also that I have the latest available version of the smartphone's software.

What else can I try? Please advise.

Comment: Restart your phone? I don't have any good ideas for this one, but restarting is always a good idea..

Comment: @aBochur That helps only temporarily. Actually, a faster solution is to reconnect the WiFi.